# Root to leaf path with maximum distinct nodes

Tags: python, c++, recursion, binary-tree

I was recently looking over the following problem [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/root-leaf-path-maximum-distinct-nodes/). Basically, you are given a binary tree and need to find the path with the highest number of distinct values. The link above encourages using a hash, but I am unsure how a hash would help in this case. In the article the following is stated:

> A simple solution is to explore all root to leaf paths. In every root
>   to leaf path, count distinct nodes and finally return the maximum
>   count.
>
> An efficient solution is to use hashing. We recursively traverse the
>   tree and maintain count of distinct nodes on path from root to current
>   node. We recur for left and right subtrees and finally return maximum
>   of two values.

I am not sure how a hash approach works better in this case (it's hard for me to see since I don't know c++). Can anyone help me translate the hashing approach to python? I have a setup a tree here:

```
class TreeNode(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
      self.val = value
      self.left = None
      self.right = None


root = TreeNode('A')

second = TreeNode('Z')
root.left = second

third = TreeNode('D')
second.left = third

fourth = TreeNode('A')
third.left = fourth

tenth = TreeNode('A')
third.right = tenth

fifth = TreeNode('A')
root.right = fifth

sixth = TreeNode('U')
fifth.left = sixth

seventh = TreeNode('Z')
fifth.right = seventh

eighth = TreeNode('Y')
seventh.right = eighth

nineth = TreeNode('B')
seventh.right = nineth
```

Which looks like

```
        A
       / \
      Z   A
     /   / \
    D   U   Z
   / \       \
  A   A       Y
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather not type the exact python answer here, since it is better for your learning process that way, but I can give you a hint. To start, your constructor looks right. The unordered_map objects would be analogous to dictionaries. For C++, an unordered_map object may be necessary, but a dictionary is not that helpful for Python. You would be better off to recursively take the maximum depth of each branch, counting only the ones for which the label has not been encountered yet. To keep track of which labels have been seen before, I would use a list or dictionary and check for membership with each leaf. Hope that works out for you.

Comment: Thats fair. The thing I don't get is how a dictionary helps? How does it look as this function starts to run? I understand the simple solution where you create a list for each path with node values, evaluate length, and then take max of all these paths. The hash/dictionary method on the other hand doesnt make sense because I feel like its not distinguishing the various paths/branches (root to leaf).